# Exporting from flexTable into Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, flextable

I have a dynamic flextable which I would like to use to export into a spreadsheet. How do I pull specific values from the flextable so that I can plug those values into a Google Spreadsheet? Some of the cells are just text, some are TextBoxes.

It is a 3 by 3 flextable (ultimately) that can be filled with a number of items based on the buttons selected by a user.

I wish I could show the code, but the project is super confidential and I can't show anything on here.  Sorry!